# SpamAssassin: Update Rules Results in Ignored Local.cf

Tags: spamassassin

I am trying to update SpamAssassin's config on my server, since for whatever reason it thinks that DNSWL is whitelisting every incoming mail message. I put adjusted scores in /etc/mail/local.cf, but the settings are ignored. I think this is because update_spamassassin_org.cf is read afterwards and the individual included files in the update_spamassassin_org directory are read even later. These settings override my attempt to disable DNSWL and tweak some other items.

How can I get SpamAssassin to read local.cf (or some other file) at the VERY end of the config processing so that it overrides any other settings?

Comment: Depends on the distribution.

Comment: I am running RHEL 5 with cPanel.

Comment: Had the same problem with Zimbra. I'm wondering if sa-update will overwrite my local.cf if I make it a symlink from the update_spamassassin_org directory.

Comment: I'm not clear how this wasn't a clear question. I did get an answer below, so it did appear answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`local.cf` is always parsed second-last, immediately before the `user-prefs`.  You need to have this file in the correct location for it to work (by default `/etc/mail/spamassassin`), but if it isn't doing what you expect, it's likely a problem with the directives you've specified (which you've not specified to us).